# Removing default namespace attributes in XML with C# - can't pass object by ref and then iterate

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I'm currently working on a buggy bit of code that's designed to strip out all the namespaces from an XML document and re-add them in the header. We use it because we ingest very large xml documents and then re-serve them in small fragments, so each item needs to replicate the namespaces in the parent document.

The XML is first loaded ias an XmlDocument and then passed to a function that removes the namespaces:

```
        _fullXml = new XmlDocument();
        _fullXml.LoadXml(itemXml);
        RemoveNamespaceAttributes(_fullXml.DocumentElement);
```

The remove function iterates through the whole documents looking for namespaces and removing them. It looks like this:

```
    private void RemoveNamespaceAttributes(XmlNode node){

        if (node.Attributes != null)
        {
            for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (node.Attributes[i].Name.Contains(':') || node.Attributes[i].Name == "xmlns")
                    node.Attributes.Remove(node.Attributes[i]);
            }
        }

        foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            RemoveNamespaceAttributes(n);
        }
    }
```

However, I've discovered that it doesn't work - it leaves all the namespaces intact.

If you iterate through the code with the debugger then it looks to be doing what it's supposed to - the nodes objects have their namespace attributes removed. But the original _fullXml document remains untouched. I assume this is because the function is looking at a clone of the data passed to it, rather than the original data.

So my first thought was to pass it by ref. But I can't do that because the iterative part of the function inside the foreach loop has a compile error - you can't pass the object n by reference.

Second thought was to pass the whole _fullXml document but that doesn't work either, guessing because it's still a clone.

So it looks like I need to solve the problem of passing the document by ref and then iterating through the nodes to remove all namespaces. This will require re-designing this code fragment obviously, but I can't see a good way to do it. Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: The `XmlDocument` should take care of the namespaces by itself. Are you sure you actually need to do this? Also, there are no clones here, passing by reference is not going to help you. And could you post a sample XML that shows the problem?

Comment: I agree (I think) with @svick - it sounds like you're still thinking of XML as some form of formatted text. Those nodes still need to belong to specific namespaces, so the Xml API may be fixing things on output. It would be more interesting to work out why the code that creates the small fragments doesn't get the namespaces correct in the first place.

Comment: It does get them correct. The problem is that we end up storing this XML as a text block in a NoSQL database. Left to its own devices the XmlDocument will add the necessary namespaces on every line of the document - which is syntactically correct, but messy and means that when we come to return it, we're not reconstituting a fragment of the original as we're supposed to. Having played around with this some more it seems as though the RemoveAttribute call simply doesn't work for namespaces. I have no idea how to remove them.

Comment: "reconstituting a fragment of the original" - is the bit I was talking about where you're still acting as if this is formatted text. The reconstituted value has *exactly* the same information content. It does have a different textual representation, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

To strip namespaces it could be done like this:

```
void StripNamespaces(XElement input, XElement output)
{
    foreach (XElement child in input.Elements())
    {
        XElement clone = new XElement(child.Name.LocalName);
        output.Add(clone);
        StripNamespaces(child, clone);
    }
    foreach (XAttribute attr in input.Attributes())
    {
        try
        {
            output.Add(new XAttribute(attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Decide how to handle duplicate attributes
            //if(e.Message.StartsWith("Duplicate attribute"))
            //output.Add(new XAttribute(attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
XElement result = new XElement("root");
StripNamespaces(NamespaceXml, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure there aren't failure cases with this but it occurs to me that you can do

```
string x = Regex.Replace(xml, @"(xmlns:?|xsi:?)(.*?)=""(.*?)""", "");
```

on the raw xml to get rid of namespaces.

It's probably not the best way to solve this but I thought I'd put it out there.